# Why doesn't the command, find ~ -name "file_name" seem to work outside the home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I use Ubuntu from the MS-Windows store.

I frequently need to be able to find files that I've downloaded or saved to a folder, and have forgotten where they are. However the files I need to look for tend to be outside the home directory.

If one starts in the home directory, and executes

`cd .. ; cd .. ; ls`

A series of directories should be available in the terminal: `mnt` is the one I go for. It contains `c`, which leads into all MS-windows directories.

Now say I need to find the file `reference.4.txt`, which is in the path `/mnt/c/Users/alexandre/Downloads`

If I execute

`find ~ -name "reference.4.txt"`

Nothing happens, but if I do the same thing for any file within my home directory,

`find ~ -name "home_directory_file"`

I get an output naming the path of the file immediately, as expected.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: If you want to direct find to search somewhere above your Linux home directory, then `find ~/../.. ` would do what your manual method does.

Comment: As a side note `/mnt` is not the place to be regularly mounting file-systems. It should be left empty, and ignored.

Comment: What is your home directory? What does `echo "$HOME"` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `~` means home directory. You could specify a different directory such as `/mnt/c`. You can even specify a list of directories e.g. `~ /mnt/c`.

Comment: I got a goofy error after giving it a go, but it wasn't difficult to work around. It works now. Thank you